# The filestream of sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, filestream

The FILESTREAM feature of SQL Server 2008, allows storage of and efficient access to BLOB data using a combination of SQL Server 2008 and the NTFS file system.

When insert a row on a table which contains varbinary column with filestream attribute, the file (data) is stored directly on the file system and assigned the new name (e.g. 00000016-00000079-0006).

Is any API of TSQL can check that which file on the file system is associated with the particular row?

Comment: I don't think I understand the question - the file name is that 00000016-00000079-0006 that you found.  Just do a select * from your filestream-enabled table, and you'll get the file name for each row, right?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: How you have overcome the Access Denied when the stream is saved?

Answer (score 2):

The file name is that 00000016-00000079-0006 that you found - look for it in the directory where you configured the FileStream storage. Just do a select * from your filestream-enabled table, and you'll get the file name for each row.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server and Filestream do not expose the physical path, as it may change at any time based on partition splits and similar operations. You can get the logical path with the PathName() method and open it through the various Filestream capable functions.